# what are the notations used for Software highlevel design?

Tags: software-design

i have been given to design software.i have designed the overall process using box and arrow notation .i want to know for high level design of software is there any specific notation to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most commonly used notations is [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) or Unified Modelling Language.